# Problem in printing a key value with multiple words

Tags: multicolumn

I am facing problem with a particular key value, not able to print with `\multicolumn` or `\textbf` while other keys works. My LaTeX code and sample data are pasted at http://pastebin.com/t5V1AK1m.

Here is min. working code is

```
\begin{tabular}{ cccccc}
    \hline
    {\bf S. No.}&{\bf Type}&{\bf Item}&{\bf D/C}&{\bf Currency}&{\bf Amount}\\
    \hline

    [% FOREACH tx = bill.transactions %]
  \\ {\bf [% tx.serial %]} & {\bf [% tx.type %]} & [% tx.item_product_code %] &  [% tx.dc %] & [% tx.currency  %] & [% tx.amount %]\\
    [% tx.comments %] \\
    %       \multicolumn{6}{c}{ [% tx.comments %] } \\
    [% END %]
    \hline\hline
    \end{tabular}
```

Problem is with tx.comment

```
[% tx.comments %] \\,
```

If I use it like this then it shows the data in variable, but it print the data under first column of table only and width of column increases with data in this.

if I tried with

```
          \multicolumn{6}{c}{ [% tx.comments %] } \\
```

but it did not work, I also tried this key to print with `\texbf` but it did not work, with `\multicolumn` it gives the below error.

> ```
> Couldn't render template "src/diner/bill_pdf.tt:
> latex error - pdflatex exited with errors: 
> ! File ended while scanning use of \multicolumn. 
> ! mergency stop. 
> !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
> ```

my sample data in comment are

```
     {
                      amount => "100.00",
                      amt_prod_serv_chgs => "100.00",
                      amt_tax => undef,
                      billid => 15,
                      comments => "chilly paneeer zsocked with juise with mali kofta and a lot of other thing which you could not imainge",
                      currency => "INR",
                      dc => "D",
                      item_count => 1,
                      item_product_code => "chillypaneeerzsockedw",
                      item_service_code => undef,
                      more_type => "",
                      price => "100.00",
                      serial => 1,
                      transactionid => 98,
                      txndate => "2016-09-23 06:53:13",
                      type => "PROD",
                      units => 1,
                    },
```

content of comments is variable. Issue is with only comments key value if I used any other key values it's work fine with multicloumn ans well textbf. What could be the cause of the different response of this key value  in two cases. I want to print in a row by using multicolumn.

Thanks 
Amit Bondwal

Comment: Please add your code to the question as a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. You are much more likely to get a reply if peolple can see your code right away rather than having to follow an external link to read it.

Comment: I updated the question with min. working code

Comment: Andrew, any help

Comment: You still haven't supplied a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). As I said, a MWE should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. Looking at what you do have the problems are caused by the comment symbols `%`. Are you generating the latex code from another program? If so it might help to explain what you are really doing. I'm about to go home but may have time to look again later.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Andrew for your time.

I solved this issue with below metthod:-

1. Without declraing width of multicolumn.

```
 \\ {\bf [% tx.serial %]} & {\bf [% tx.type %]} & [% tx.item_product_code %] &  [% tx.dc %] & [% tx.currency  %] & [% tx.amount %]\\
 \multicolumn{6}{c}\bf [% tx.comments %]
```

2. with declaring width of multicolumn for content wraapper, by declaring table inside multicolumn

```
 \\ {\bf [% tx.serial %]} & {\bf [% tx.type %]} & [% tx.item_product_code %] &  [% tx.dc %] & [% tx.currency  %] & [% tx.amount %]\\ 
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\begin{tabular}[t]{p{4in}} 
Details: [% tx.comments %]   </code>
     \end{tabular}}\\
```

I am open for more suggestion to accomplish it neat and clean.
Thanks..